# PairRDD from SQL

Tags: apache-spark

Is it possible to have a pair RDD from the below SQL query.
The pair being ((item_id, flight_id), metric1)
item_id, flight_id  are part of group by.

```sql
SELECT
  item_id,
  flight_id,
  SUM(metric1) AS metric1
FROM mytable
GROUP BY
  item_id,
  flight_id
```

Comment: Yes, of course! df.rdd.map( // transform row to pair)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As as mentioned by [eliasah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3415409/eliasah) you can simply map over a RDD (with optional `rdd` between query and `map`) as follows:

```scala
sqlContext.sql(query).map{case Row(item_id: U, flight_id: V, metric1: T) =>
  ((item_id, flight_id), metric1)}
```

Where `T`, `U`, `V` are types of data, `sqlContext` is a `SQLContext` instance and query is a query provided in your question.